# Finding a repeated character in a string

Tags: java, string, character, repeat

The problem states the following: given a string and a character by the user find the number of times the character (given by the user) repeats itself in the string (also given by the user).

I have this piece of code

```
public int repeticion (int s){
        int return = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write a string: ");
        String chain = in.next();
        System.out.println("Write the character: ");
        String character = in.next();
        if (chain.contains(character)) {
            cont = cont + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("The character repeats itself "+cont+"times");
        return return;
```

But as you can see the `.contains` only counts the character once, not the number of times it appears in the string.

Comment: `contains` just checks **if** character appears in string, not **how many times** it appears. You need to iterate over each character and compare it with user character. Try using `yourString.charAt(index)` to get character at specified index. Remember that index can be in range from `0` till `yourString.length() - 1`.

Answer (score 4):

**.contains()** only says that a character exists within a string, not how many. You need to iterate over each character of a string to check if it equals the character you are searching for.

```
String chain = "your string";
int cont = 0;
for(int i=0; i<chain.length(); i++) {
   if(chain.charAt(i) == character) {
      cont++;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also repeatedly check that the character is in the string, get that index, then check the substring from after that index to the end of the string. I recommend the following:

```
int index = 0;
int count = 0;
while (chain.indexof(character, index) != -1  && index < chain.length()-1) {
    index = chain.indexof(character, index) + 1;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contains will simply tell you if the character is present.  To actually count the number of times that character would appear, you'll need to iterate over the string and count the number of times the selected character appears.  This method will work:

```
public countACharacter(char thecharacter, String stringtocountcharactersin) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < stringtocountcharactersin.length(); i++) {
        if(stringtocountcharactersin.charAt(i) == thecharacter) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Duplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int distinct = 0;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter STRING : -");
        String s = br.readLine();
        try {
            for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                while (s != null) {
                    s = s.trim();
                    for (j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                            distinct++;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + "--" + distinct);
                    String d = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
                    s = s.replaceAll(d, " ");
                    distinct = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a description of why you believe this answers the question? It's difficult to see what you are doing without that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void chars( String a, char k)
       {
           String z=""+k;
           int s=0;
           for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)

           {

               if(z.equals(a.substring(i,i+1)))
                   s++;

                                            }

           System.out.println(s);
       }
```

you can achieve your goal this way you're taking the integer s without any reason and what you're doing wrong is you are using .contains() method instead of that you should compare the given char with each char of the string and use a counter for maintaining number of times of the character or you can do it this way by converting the char into a string by concatenating it with an empty string("") and then use .equals method like i have used in my code.

Answer (score -1):

//With out string methods.
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String ss="rajesh kumar";

    Field value = null;
    try {
        value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // It's private so we need to explicitly make it accessible.

    value.setAccessible(true);

    try {
        char[] values = (char[])value.get(ss);

        //String is converted to char array with out string functions

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<values.length;j++)
            {
                if(values[i]== values[j])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n Count of :"+values[i] +"="+count);

        }

        System.out.println("Values "+values[1]);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}